# Joining Multiple table to fetch email id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

I have 3 models

**aff.rb**

```
has_many :tic_affs, inverse_of: :aff, dependent: :restrict_with_exception
has_many :tic, through: :tic_affs
```

**tic.rb**

```
has_one  :tic_aff, inverse_of: :tic, dependent: :restrict_with_exception
has_one  :aff, through: :tic_aff
```

**use.rb**

```
has_one :aff, inverse_of: :use, dependent: :restrict_with_exception
has_many :tics, class_name: "Tic"
```

i want to fetch email id from user table using joins could any one please help me in framing the Rails query

This is the query i wrote to fetch email id's

```
select uses.email 
from tic_affs 
FULL OUTER JOIN affs ON tic_affs.aff_id=affs.id 
JOIN uses ON affs.use_id=uses.id;
```

if this query is right help me framing this into rails query

Comment: Your table names don't match with model's expected table names(i.e. `ticket_affiliates` instead of `tic_affs`,  `affiliates` instead of `affs`), is there something you've not mentioned or omitted here by mistake?

Comment: Sorry I have omitted consider it as tic_affs